# What's the most recent Richfaces version supported by the last release of JBoss Seam (2.3.1.Final)?

Tags: jakarta-ee, richfaces, seam

I found at the Seam framework last version [release notes](https://issues.jboss.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=12319995&styleName=Text&projectId=10071) an issue mentioning an upgrade of the Richfaces suported to version 4.3.3.Final. I also found on Brian Leathem's blog [this post](http://www.bleathem.ca/blog/2014/10/richfaces-450final-release-announcement.html) stating that the 4.5.x RichFaces releases will focus on compatibility with 4.3.x.

My question is: Will the latest version of RF (4.5.2) work well with the last version of JBoss Seam (2.3.1.Final), since it's set to work with RF 4.3.3.Final which is supposed to be compatible with RF 4.5x?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of RichFaces (4.5.x) won't work with Seam 2.3 it seems, see:
https://developer.jboss.org/message/936866?et=watches.email.thread#936866
(the resources packed.js, packed.css etc cannot be loaded)

I have the same problem. It seems the RichFaces team couldn't care less. They have announced that they will 'pursue a path of stability and not innovation' (http://www.bleathem.ca/blog/2014/07/richfaces-will-pursue-stability-over-innovation.html). With that they won't get any new projects to adopt RichFaces yet they are ignoring all the projects that used the old JBoss dream team of Seam+RichFaces!

I have it working with Seam 2.3.1 and RichFaces 4.3.4 but there are a couple of bad bugs in RF 4.3.4 (try using a scrollable table on an iPad or Mac) and these are fixed in RF 4.5.

I guess I will need to kick out RF completely and concentrate on Primefaces.